# qmake not finding right mkspec

Tags: raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, qmake, configure

I am trying to use the qmake that I just compiled from opensource.  I compiled on a RH9 host, building it for arm64 so that I could cross compile for Raspberry.  My pwd was /raspi/build when I ran the following configure:

```
../qt-everywhere-src-6.5.0/configure -release -no-opengl -device linux-rasp-pi3-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/raspi/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.mpacbti-rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi- -sysroot /raspi/sysroot -opensource -confirm-license -skip qtwayland -skip qtlocation -skip qtscript -make libs -prefix /raspi/qt6 -no-use-gold-linker -no-gbm
```

which should have placed the compiled code into /raspi/qt6/bin/qmake.  So now when I create my makefile for my test program using /raspi/qt6/bin/qmake is get this error:

```
Info: creating stash file /tmp/myapp/bin/debug/.qmake.stash
Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'g++'. Output:
===================
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
g++: error: unrecognized command-line option '-mfpu=crypto-neon-fp-armv8'
g++: error: unrecognized command-line option '-mfloat-abi=hard'
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-host-pie --enable-host-bind-now --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugs.almalinux.org/ --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-gcc-major-version-only --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --without-isl --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-cet --with-tune=generic --with-arch_64=x86-64-v2 --with-arch_32=x86-64 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto --enable-link-serialization=1
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.3.1 20220421 (Red Hat 11.3.1-2) (GCC)
===================
Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?
```

which makes no sense.  The configured with line looks nothing like what I used to configure.  So using find command I found another qmake in my build directory so I ran that instead:

```
Using qmake: /raspi/build/qtbase/bin/qmake
Could not find qmake spec 'devices/linux-rasp-pi3-g++'.
Error processing project file: /project/myapp.pro
```

So that's not working either.  I tried to find the mkspecs for what I think is the right one:

```
../qt6/bin/qmake -query
QT_SYSROOT:
QT_INSTALL_PREFIX:/raspi/qt6
QT_INSTALL_ARCHDATA:/raspi/qt6
QT_INSTALL_DATA:/raspi/qt6
QT_INSTALL_DOCS:/raspi/qt6/doc
QT_INSTALL_HEADERS:/raspi/qt6/include
QT_INSTALL_LIBS:/raspi/qt6/lib
QT_INSTALL_LIBEXECS:/raspi/qt6/libexec
QT_INSTALL_BINS:/raspi/qt6/bin
QT_INSTALL_TESTS:/raspi/qt6/tests
QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS:/raspi/qt6/plugins
QT_INSTALL_QML:/raspi/qt6/qml
QT_INSTALL_TRANSLATIONS:/raspi/qt6/translations
QT_INSTALL_CONFIGURATION:
QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES:/raspi/qt6/examples
QT_INSTALL_DEMOS:/raspi/qt6/examples
QT_HOST_PREFIX:/raspi/qt6
QT_HOST_DATA:/raspi/qt6
QT_HOST_BINS:/raspi/qt6/bin
QT_HOST_LIBEXECS:/raspi/qt6/libexec
QT_HOST_LIBS:/raspi/qt6/lib
QMAKE_SPEC:devices/linux-rasp-pi3-g++
QMAKE_XSPEC:devices/linux-rasp-pi3-g++
QMAKE_VERSION:3.1
QT_VERSION:6.5.0
```

So why is qmake not finding the spec directory?